# Bootcamp Windows 10 - No image are available

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos

For those that don't know yet, [Bootcamp no longer requires (supports) USB drive](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/30/el-cap-boot-camp-no-usb/) to install Windows.

I'm trying to install Windows 10 but getting a "No image are available" notice on Windows setup window after entering the license key.

I haven't found a single result about this online (so far). Any ideas?

Thanks...

> El-Capitan on Early 2015/MBP 13".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I used an old product Win 7 Pro product key thinking I could upgrade (iso was Win 10 `single language`) it stated no images available when I entered my old key.

When I skipped entering a product key, it brought up the iso image as expected.

On the second computer, I downloaded the first `english` image from Microsoft and it accepted the pro key.  Very strange that the `single language` image meant home only (not pro).

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. The key wasn't "valid" according to microsoft but it's all sorted now.